# panda: csv to dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file in following format:

> id, category
>
> 1, apple
>
> 2, orange
>
> 3, banana

I need to read this file and populate a dictionary which has ids as key and categories as value.

I am trying to use panda, but its to_dict function us returning a dictionary with a a single key-value pair. Key is another dictionary containing 1,2,3 as entries and value too is a dictionary containing apple, orange, banana.

What I want is three key-value entriesm like 1 -> apple, 2 -> ornge, 3 -> banana.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create index by first column and then convert Series `df['category']` to dictionary:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0)

d = df['category'].to_dict()
```

Or if only 2 columns csv is possible create Series by `index_col=0` and `squeeze=True` parameters and convert to dicts:

```
d = pd.read_csv('file.csv', index_col=0, squeeze=True).to_dict()
```

Or if more columns and dont need index by first column use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')

d = df.set_index('id')['category'].to_dict()
```

Comment: also `df.squeeze().to_dict()` with the first method :)

Comment: Is it also possible to plot a chart showing frequency distribution of category data?